# How can I fix backspace autocorrection in vscode console?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, .net-core

When using Visual Studio Code on Windows through WSL 2 (Ubuntu 20.04) I came across a very peculiar behavior - when opening console programs of C# through the integrated terminal (bash, of course), on System.Console.ReadLine() the input could not be properly erased - on pressing the backspace button, the last symbol would be interchanged with the semicolon ';', a random number (usually one or two digits, probably related to the column position within the console, however, I am not certain) and a letter 'R'. For example, the string "before" turns into "befor;6R" after one backspace press.
Additionally:

- There is no such problem with the input in C++ console programs from the integrated terminal.
- The problem does not recur when the same file is opened with the bash console outside of vscode
- The problem persists within vscode in case opening the console application directly and through "dotnet run" command.

The program's listing is provided below:

```
namespace helloCSharp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string s = System.Console.ReadLine() ?? "default";
            System.Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me find the root of the problem and find a way to fix it.

Comment: So you're running the C# application in the WSL console? Or are you running VS Code in the WSL console (why)? Which .NET version are you using?

Comment: .NET version is 5.0.202. I run the C# application in the WSL console. And the problem occurs when the console is accessed through the integrated terminal of VS code.